# MimeUtility decode code can't work on cloud

Tags: apache-spark-sql, decode, google-cloud-dataproc, quoted-printable

I have a hive udf for cleaning text, the text is encoded with "quoted-printable", this is the code I refer from online:

```
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(text.getBytes());
    try {
        InputStream isAfterDecode = MimeUtility.decode(is, "quoted-printable");
        text = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(isAfterDecode, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                .lines()
                .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

When I test it on my IDEA, it worked fine. However, when I packaged it as a Hive function jar and uploaded to Cloud(Dataproc) to use it by SparkSql, it can't work. Do I need to do anything else?

I though it may be caused by the environment?